# Menu item hidden behind others

Tags: menus, css

I'm having some issues with my menu being displayed properly. As you can see from the photo below, my 3rd level menu items are hidden behind the others for some reason. I've gone over my template I'm using and things seem to be alright on that end, otherwise the menu option wouldn't even be displayed. Thus I'm thinking something is wrong with my CSS, though I can't see what that would be. Does anyone have any ideas as to what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full menu code?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the php code? IF so, then you can view it here: http://pastebin.com/BztNyKM7

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this is definitely a CSS issue.

To get the 3rd level menu to show up fully, you'll want to target it and move it X number of pixels from the left until it lines up correctly. If your sub-menu's have a set width, then use that set width to move the 3rd level into the correct position.

For example if my sub-menu's had a fixed width of 200px I'd do:

```
/* Target the 3rd level nav */
ul.menu ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu{
  position:absolute; /* Position absolute so we can move the nav element */
  left: 200px; /* Move the nav element 200px from the left based on the width we set above */
  top:0; /* Align the tertiary nav list to the top of the parent menu list */
}
```

Check out the codepen here for a full working demo sans dropdown. http://codepen.io/iandbanks/pen/PwdKeB